# Why aren't 3D models being rendered correctly over the detected ArUco marker?

Tags: java, android, opencv, graphics, 3d

Me and my teammates are working on a project, we use OpenCV to detect ArUco markers and use Rajawali (OpenGL ES wrapper library, on github) to render 3D objects over the detected markers.
We know our detection is correct, because we test it using the `drawAxis` method and it's incredibly stable and accurate. So this should rule out calibration and detection errors.
Here's how the axis look, drawn over a marker on my laptop. It isn't a video, but trust me, it's consistent across most distance/angle configurations I tried so I think it's pretty good.

[image]
This leaves nothing but the rendering method, which produces *very* wrong results.
Once we start trying to render an object over the marker:

1. Orientation gets butchered. Model is *rarely* oriented correctly with respect to the marker. Feels like it's almost not even rotating, just floating on the screen.
2. Translation also gets butchered. Model is never "stuck" to the marker, instead it moves almost always with the center of the camera (as if it's locked to the camera, not to the marker).
3. Model jitters slightly, unstable. Totally unlike the axis. Even when I hold the camera totally still.
   3 is a problem we can probably live with, but 1 and 2 are too much.
   Here's the method that renders the object, it's in Java but I think it's pretty accessible to non-Java users as well.
   This is how markers are detected (rvec and tvec values):

```
    /**
     * This method takes a gray frame, detects the markers
     * and stores their corners, rvecs, tvecs and ids,
     * then updates the detectedMarkers list with the new markers detected.
     * @param frameGray
     */
    public void markerDetection(Mat frameGray)
    {
        ids = new Mat();
        corners = new ArrayList<>();
        Aruco.detectMarkers(frameGray, markerDictionary, corners, ids);

        List<MarkerData> newDetectedMarkers = new ArrayList<>();

        if(ids.size().height > 0)
        {
            rvecs = new Mat();
            tvecs = new Mat();
            Aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, markerLength, cameraMatrix, distortionCoef, rvecs, tvecs);

            for(int i=0; i<ids.size().height; i++)
            {
                double[] rvecArray = new double[]{
                        rvecs.get(i , 0)[0],
                        rvecs.get(i , 0)[1],
                        rvecs.get(i , 0)[2]};
                double[] tvecArray = new double[]{
                        tvecs.get(i , 0)[0],
                        tvecs.get(i , 0)[1],
                        tvecs.get(i , 0)[2]};

                MarkerData newMarker = new MarkerData(rvecArray, tvecArray, corners.get(i), (int)ids.get(i, 0)[0]);
                newDetectedMarkers.add(newMarker);
            }
        }

        updateDetectedMarkers(newDetectedMarkers);
    }
```

This is how rendering is done:

```
    @Override
    protected void onRender(long elapsedRealtime, double deltaTime) {
        super.onRender(elapsedRealtime, deltaTime);
        getCurrentScene().clearChildren();
        List<MarkerData> markerData = markerDetector.getDetectedMarkers();
        for (MarkerData marker : markerData) {
            try {
                int id = R.raw.monkey;
                LoaderOBJ parser = new LoaderOBJ(mContext.getResources(), mTextureManager, id);
                parser.parse();

                Object3D object = parser.getParsedObject();
                object.setMaterial(defaultMaterial);
                object.setScale(0.3);

                Mat rvec = marker.getRvec(); // 3x1 Mat
                Mat tvec = marker.getTvec(); // 3x1 Mat

                object.setRotation(new Vector3(rvec.get(0, 0)[0], rvec.get(1, 0)[0], rvec.get(2, 0)[0]));
                object.setPosition(new Vector3(tvec.get(0, 0)[0], tvec.get(1,  0)[0], tvec.get(2, 0)[0]));

                getCurrentScene().addChild(object);
            } catch (ParsingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

markerData is a List of MarkerData objects, which contain `rvec`, `tvec`, `corners` and `id` of every detected marker.
object is the parsed 3D object, in this case it's the Suzanne monkey object.
We get the rvec and tvec associated with the current marker, and store them in `rvec` and `tvec`.
We use them to set the rotation and set the position of the object, and the rest is up to rajawali.
I am sure we are missing some Linear Algebra magic here and there, but we aren't really well versed in that area. What are we missing? How can we get this right? Help will be super appreciated.
This is my guess, and I hope it's a good guess. Good enough for anyone to help, anyways.

Comment: can you show hiw you compute and set R and T? Can you try to really feed identical images to your pipeline? Check whether R and T then stay identical over all the frames. Of they still change, maybe you update R and T in a wrong way.

Comment: @Micka sure, I just edited the question to include the method that detects the markers every frame (updates rvecs and tvecs). I doubt this is the problem because as I mentioned we are able to drawAxis easily and accurately with the rvecs and tvecs detected by this method

Comment: what does updateDetectedMarkers do? Is the same object information used for rendering coordinate axis and the object itself?

Comment: @Micka updateDetectedMarkers is only `this.detectedMarkers = detectedMarkers;`. Sets the member List of MarkerData to the passed List of marker data. drawAxis doesn't use markerData as it uses `rvecs` and `tvecs` directly, but the `rvec` and `tvec` values in markerData are the same as the ones in `rvecs` and `tvecs` because we set them through the `rvecs` and `tvecs` as is shown in the code.

Comment: currentScene is resetted before each image? Is the scene rendered with static camera position? Can you still debug/verify that rvec and tvec are the same as at the time when the coordinate axes are rendered? For axes rendering do you use openCV or the scene rendering?

Comment: Afaik coordinate axis directions are different in openCV and openGL. In OpenCV: x axis pointing in the right side from the camera, y axis pointing down, and z pointing in the direction camera is faced. IN OpenGL afair it is x: right, y: up; z: backward